# What’s the difference between a user-owned project and repository project board

Tags: git, github

I create a project and link it to a repo and create another project inside the same repo. They seem to be independent and i really don’t know the difference.

Three kinds of boards are discussed in the link below:
https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-project-board

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Project boards on GitHub help you organize and prioritize your work. You can create project boards for specific feature work, comprehensive roadmaps, or even release checklists. With project boards, you have the flexibility to create customized workflows that suit your needs.
>   Project boards are made up of issues, pull requests, and notes that are categorized as cards in columns of your choosing. You can drag and drop or use keyboard shortcuts to reorder cards within a column, move cards from column to column, and change the order of columns.

- **User-owned** project boards can contain issues and pull requests from any personal repository.
- **Repository** project boards are scoped to issues and pull requests within a single repository. They can also include notes that reference issues and pull requests in other repositories.

Basically, a user-owned project is something that can combine your repos and make them into a project, while a repository project is more limited and refers only to PRs and Issues in that repo, without knowing about your user-owned projects. You are correct to say that they seem different