# what is the difference between github project and project inside repository?

Tags: github, project, project-management, github-projects

I know this question sounds dumb, but I am unable to understand the difference between the main project and project option provided inside each repository.

Are they same? (But the URL differs)

I looked at [help.github.com](https://help.github.com)

but it doesn't help.

I basically understand that for larger projects management, project inside repository is helpful.

on what uses cases, they provided the another project outside of repository and linking those repositories to it?

Is that for structuring?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What’s the difference between a user-owned project and repository project board](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58323430/what-s-the-difference-between-a-user-owned-project-and-repository-project-board)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a repository on github (sometimes called a "project") where you store your code. You change the code, make a git commit, and push those code changes to the github repository.

GitHub also has a feature called "projects" which provides you a method for managing the work that needs to be done on the code. GitHub also has "issues", an issue tracker. You can use the GitHub Project Board to organize your GitHub issues, giving you a way to see see where things are at in your effort on the code.

You can turn off the "projects" and "issues" features in the repository settings, you don't have to use them. The center of work is the code in the repository, which might be referred to as a project -- the Projects feature lets you manage your issues in GitHub in a more visual format.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is in the scope. The "main project" (**user-owned project board**) can have issues and pull requests from multiple repositories whereas the "project in repository" (**repository project board**) can contain only the issues and pull requests belonging to that repository.

From the [Project boards docs](https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-your-work-on-github/about-project-boards):

> Types of project boards:
>
> - **User-owned project boards** can contain issues and pull requests from any personal repository.
> - **Organization-wide project boards** can contain issues and pull requests from any repository that belongs to an organization. You can link up to twenty-five repositories to your organization or user-owned project board...
> - **Repository project boards** are scoped to issues and pull requests within a single repository. They can also include notes that reference issues and pull requests in other repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this functionality has currently been remove from the "New" Projects (currently beta). https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/52841